# ASP.NET MVC Web - Como separar a performance entre os módulos de um projeto?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, aplicação-web, desempenho, iis

Explicando a dúvida. Dentro do meu sistema existem alguns menus, vamos usar como exemplo 3, nomeando-os A, B e C, cada um sendo um módulo de CRUD com algum tipo de relatório. Se 300 pessoas estiverem usando o módulo A, impactará na performance do módulo B, certo? 300 pessoas requisitando alguma coisa do banco ao mesmo tempo, etc. Sem contar que influencia também na performance do servidor que o sistema estiver publicado (IIS), até ai está correto? Me corrijam se eu estiver enganado, por favor.Isso conta para qualquer outro módulo. Como eu faço para um módulo em específico não influenciar na performance de outros módulos? É o que o cliente está pedindo para fazer em um único módulo. Será que API resolveria? Não conheço a usabilidade da API. Se alguém aqui conhecer e me disser que isso separaria esse "problema" de performance, buscarei mais informações para poder desenvolver. Ou Web-Service? Enfim, de imediato meu gerente de projeto 'sugeriu' fazer outro projeto mvc mesmo, separando também os bancos, e chamar por iframe. Seria a melhor solução? To achando muito gambiarra fazer isso, e também ainda não sei como ficaria a parte de validar o login, já que viria do sistema 'original', e não do projeto que estiver dentro do iframe.

Answer (score 5):

Como o Cigano já elencou muito bem os pontos da sua duvida e respondeu à altura, vou apenas sugerir alguns links e fazer alguns sugestões de tecnologias à serem utilizadas.

Como está à utilizar o `ASP.NET MVC` verifique se todas as suas `Action`s estão marcadas com retorno `async Task<>`.

Então onde você encontrar.:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAction(int id)
    {
        var model = db.Colecao.Find(id);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

altere para.:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction(int id)
    {
        var model = await db.Colecao.FindAsync(id);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

O mesmo vale para WebAPI, então se encontrar.:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public Entidade MyAction(int id)
    {
        var model = db.Colecao.Find(id); 
        return model;
    }
}
```

altere para.:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<Entidade> MyAction(int id)
    {
        var model = await db.Colecao.FindAsync(id);
        return model;
    }
}
```

Com isto, você torna as suas Actions Assíncronas, com esta simples alteração o seu sistema pode vir a suportar milhares de requisições por minuto, como você pode ver no seguinte [`Artigo/Benchmarking - Node.js vs. IIS + WebAPI async – Performance Test`](https://tipaltilabs.com/2016/07/09/node-js-vs-iis-webapi-async/)

Agora quanto ao `Banco de Dados`, você pode e deve fazer uso e abuso do `Entity Framework` para acelerar o seu desenvolvimento, apenas lembre-se de utilizar os métodos assíncronos sempre que estes estiverem disponíveis.: como por exemplo `FindAsync`, `ToListAsync`, `ToDictionaryAsync`, `FirstOrDefaultAsync`, `AnyAsync`, `MeuMetodoAsync`.

Mas lembre-se, o `Entity Framework` é apenas uma ferramenta, nada impede que você utilize outra em conjunto com ela, como por Exemplo o `Dapper`, aconselho que utilize o `Dapper` sempre que tiver uma consulta mais critica para o sistema, seja por ser muito requisitada ou caso precise escrever o seu proprio `SQL`, em todo caso, não esqueça de usar  os métodos `Async`, como o `QueryAsync`
. Segue um link para justificar este conselho.: [`Dapper vs Entity Framework vs ADO.NET Performance Benchmarking`](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/dapper-vs-entity-framework-vs-ado-net-performance-benchmarking/)

Quanto ao seu `front-end`, como não sei o conhecimento que à sua equipe tem de JavaScript, aconselharia que vocês colocassem de lado o `jQuery` e usem o `VueJS`, mesmo que decidam fazer uma `Multiple Page Application`.

**Modelo**

```
public class Entidade
{
    public Int32 EntidadeID { get; set; }
    public String Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction(int id)
    {
        var model = await db.Colecao.FindAsync(id);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@model Entidade
<div id="conteudo">
    <input type="hidden" id="EntidadeID" name="EntidadeID" v-model="EntidadeID">
    <label>
        Descrição: 
        <input type="text" id="Descricao" name="Descricao" v-model="Descricao">
    </label>
</div>
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var model = @(Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));
        new Vue({
            el: '#conteudo',
            data: model
        });
    </script>
}
```

A primeira vista parece uma troca ruim (O `Razor` pelo `Vue`), mas lembre-se, você estará transferindo à responsabilidade de renderizar a pagina para o `Cliente`, e ficará bem mais simples para atualizar a pagina após requisições `AJAX` (devido ao `bind bi-direcional` criado pelo `VueJS`).

Para saber mais, acesse os links.: [`VueJS`](https://vuejs.org), [`Vue JS Brasil`](http://www.vuejs-brasil.com.br) e [`Vue.js is easier to learn than jQuery`](https://medium.com/js-dojo/vue-js-is-easier-to-learn-than-jquery-abbbb9c12cf8).

Lembrando que a adoção do `VueJS` pode ser incremental, você não precisa reescrever toda a sua aplicação para poder começar a utilizar o mesmo.

Claro, que você pode vir a fazer uma aplicação `SPA`, usando o `Async WebAPI` e o `Framework JavaScript` de sua preferencia, tais como `Angular`, `React` ou o proprio `VueJS`, segue um link de tutorial [`VueJS - Single Page Application`](http://www.vuejs-brasil.com.br/tag/single-page-application/)

Comment: Agradeço as dicas, e pode ter certeza que estudarei esses casos. O sistema foi desenvolvido em 2012, e vários e vários desenvolvedores programaram no projeto, cada um usando suas práticas de desenvolvimento, e em alguns casos, 'inpráticas' de desenvolvimento, ta um verdadeiro frankenstein. Umas semanas atrás cheguei a pensar a dar uma olhada nessa questão de usar async nas actions, pois precisei usar em uma action em específico. Se eu alterar todas as actions para async não correrei o risco de dar algum problema então?

Comment: Neste caso, aconselho que faça isto de forma progressiva, escreva as funcionalidades novas desta forma, e quando precisar alterar uma antiga, modifique ela para atender este novo modelo. Quanto à trocar o ActionResult pelo async Task<ActionResult>, não deve impactar a sua solução, mesmo assim eu faria esta alteração aos poucos.

Answer (score 2):

> Se 300 pessoas estiverem usando o módulo A, impactará na performance do módulo B, certo?

Sim, porque é um sistema só, mas 300 pessoas normalmente não faz nem cócegas no serviço se você usa as práticas corretas para bancos de dados, assincronismo e boas estratégias de *cache*.

> 300 pessoas requisitando alguma coisa do banco ao mesmo tempo, etc. Sem contar que influencia também na performance do servidor que o sistema estiver publicado (IIS), até ai está correto?

Sim, mas, como eu falei, é muito cedo para pensar em resolver performance. Primeiro você precisa medir como o servidor se comporta antes de propor algo para resolver, no sentido de modularização, que é o que sua pergunta se propõe a elucidar.

> Como eu faço para um módulo em específico não influenciar na performance de outros módulos?

Como eu disse, usando as práticas corretas para bancos de dados, assincronismo e boas estratégias de *cache*.

> Será que API resolveria? Não conheço a usabilidade da API. Se alguém aqui conhecer e me disser que isso separaria esse "problema" de performance, buscarei mais informações para poder desenvolver. Ou Web-Service?

(Web) API e Web Service são quase a mesma coisa. A diferença é que um implementa REST e outro implementa SOAP. Independente da implementação, isso pouco ou nada influencia na questão de performance como um todo.

> Enfim, de imediato meu gerente de projeto 'sugeriu' fazer outro projeto mvc mesmo, separando também os bancos, e chamar por iframe. Seria a melhor solução?

De forma alguma. O trabalho do servidor é o mesmo e ainda incorre numa má prática de usar `<iframe>` onde não precisa.

> To achando muito gambiarra fazer isso, e também ainda não sei como ficaria a parte de validar o login, já que viria do sistema 'original', e não do projeto que estiver dentro do iframe.

E de fato, é.

Se precisar de consultoria a respeito, veja no meu perfil meus meios de contato. Posso fazer uma consultoria mais aprofundada a respeito do seu problema.

Comment: Só para complementar [Node.js vs. IIS + WebAPI async – Performance Test](https://tipaltilabs.com/2016/07/09/node-js-vs-iis-webapi-async/), como você pode ver, o IIS consegue processar 100.000 requisições por minuto. E quanto ao Banco de Dados [Dapper vs Entity Framework vs ADO.NET Performance Benchmarking](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/dapper-vs-entity-framework-vs-ado-net-performance-benchmarking/), depedendo da requisição ela leva menos de 1 milissegundo.

Comment: Tirando a parte que iframe é uma má prática, você disse que o trabalho do servidor seria o mesmo. Porém, esse projeto chamado por iframe estaria em outro servidor, e o banco de dados também, separado do banco 'original'.

Comment: @Yoshitani e os dois bancos se comunicariam por Linked Server? Se Sim... Já até consigo sentir o seu sofrimento no futuro ;D

Comment: Eles não se comunicariam. O que eu preciso usar do banco 'original', faço via consulta sql mesmo. E as FK do novo banco, estão sem relacionamento. Foi a única coisa que pensei para fazer do jeito que me requisitaram.

Comment: @Yoshitani ao invés de quebrar o seu banco de dados, tente identificar onde está o gargalo, se o gargalo for de `IO`, tente colocar o arquivo de `Dados`, `Log` e `arquivo de indices` em `HD`s diferentes, se não resolver, crie [`Filegroups`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups) e distribua as suas tabelas neles. Agora se o problema for de CPU, crie um [`Cluster de SqlServer`](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/02/introduction-sql-server-clusters/)

Comment: Você ainda não me respondeu se você tem um gargalo de desempenho ou não. Se a ideia é ~separar por módulos~, colocando fisicamente um servidor e um banco por módulo, a comunicação entre eles deve ser por Web API.

Answer (score 1):

Eu endosso as respostas do Cigano, porém na questão abaixo , sou de outra opinião. Mas não quer dizer que é a minha resposta ou a dele seja certo ou errado, nem pior ou melhor.

> Enfim, de imediato meu gerente de projeto 'sugeriu' fazer outro projeto mvc mesmo, separando também os bancos, e chamar por iframe. Seria a melhor solução?

Procure **nunca** usar `IFRAME`, realmente é uma péssima prática - gambiarra mesmo. Mas separar os módulos, cada um em um projeto, isso sim é cabível de conversar. Já ví muitos projetos onde não existe a necessidade de ter um projeto monolítico, e o sistema começa a se tornar complexo apenas pelo fato de tentar manter tudo em um ambiente só. E se for segmentado, tudo fica mais claro e leve.

Não é complicado começar a entender se essa separação é interessante. Uma pré analise, bem superficial, que começo é perguntando: Qual é o fluxo dos dados? Se a resposta for algo tipo:

1. A entidade/dado é iniciada e preparada no Módulo A;
2. O módulo B apenas trata de informações que o Módulo A permitir;
3. O módulo C apenas trata de informações que o Módulo B permitir;

Assim é fácil ver que os módulos são totalmente desacoplados. Podem ser facilmente projetos diferentes, base de dados independentes, e tudo mais.

Um exemplo legal é de uma loja, onde vc pode ter 3 sistemas totalmente independentes:

1. **LOGISTICA (PHP+MySQL)**: De compras e recepção de novos produtos. Após o produto pronto para ser vendido, é enviado para a LOJA.
2. **LOJA (SAP+NodeJS+MongoDB)**: Recebe o produto, publica na loja, adiciona no carrinho de compras e efetua a venda.
3. **CONTABILIDADE (ASP.NET+SQLServer)**: Recebe o pedido de compra, valida e efetiva a venda, dispara mensagem para a logística fazer a entrega.

Uma solução, mas vários projetos, com várias tecnologias. A Logistica não precisa saber que existem usuários clientes, nem processos de compras. A Loja não precisa saber que existem procedimentos de entrega de caminhões, como os produtos são organizados no estoque, etc. E a Contabilidade só precisa saber de ordens de compra, e dinheiro, de nada precisa saber de clientes ou caminhões.

Enfim, separar sua solução por escopo de responsabilidades é saudável sim, desde que necessário e saiba como fazer.

Comment: Entendo, mas uma dúvida: no exemplo que citou, como a LOJA faria parte do mesmo sistema que a LOGISTICA, sendo que cada um seria um menu no sistema como um todo. Vou usar esta página que estou agora do stackoverflow mesmo, tem os menus 'Perguntas', 'Tags', 'Usuários', passando o mouse em cima podemos ver que o link é o mesmo, apenas alterando após o "/", o que eu gostaria de fazer é que o menu "Usuários" por exemplo, não influenciasse na performance do resto. Podendo ter milhões de usuário usando, deixando lento apenas a página usuários, e não o sistema inteiro.

Comment: Mas cada `/modulo` pode ser uma aplicação diferente, sem problemas. No IIS vc pode criar `Application Folders`, ou então vc pode criar subdomains como `moduloA.seudominio.com`, `moduloB.seudominio.com`. Então isso não é um problema, vc apenas deve escolher como irá publicar suas aplicações.

Comment: No exemplo que fiz, a LOJA terá milhoes de acessos, enquanto demais serão acessadas apenas pelos funcionários da loja. E pode ter no menu `loja.com`, `loja.com/logistica`, loja.com/contabilidade` sem problemas.

Comment: Então, mas estando no mesmo servidor, esses milhões de acesso na LOJA, impactaria na performance da logística, não?

Comment: Vc pode isolar o processamento da aplicação de forma a limitar o consumo de recursos. Outra coisa é que não se é obrigatório hospedar a aplicação no mesmo servidor. O ideal é cada aplicação ter sua hospedagem

Comment: Principalmente se tivermos falando de hospedagem em nuvem. Se for o caso, outra ls preocupações devem ser levantadas afim de se obter o máximo de aproveitamento do seu provedor de nuvem.